# Could not find the association, Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :roles, :through => :memberships
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end
```

and my View

```
<% for role in Role.find(:all) %>
      <div>
        <%=check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.roles.include?(role) %>
        <%=role.name%>
      </div>
     <% end %>
```

I've got next error on my View  - Could not find the association :memberships in model User
and i can't understand why this is happens ..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to explicitly state `has_many :memberships`, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :memberships
   has_many :roles, :through => :memberships
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end
```

Add that in, and you should be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason,

I'll need to add

```
has_many :memberships
```

to my User and Role models.

Thanks anyway ! :)