# Could not find the association :item_option in model Item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :options, through: :item_option

end

class ItemOption < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :option

end
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :items, through: :item_option


end
```

I tried changing `:item_option` to `item_options` or `items_options`, no help.

Why do I keep getting that error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not find the association, Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352595/could-not-find-the-association-rails-3)

Answer (score 2):

You should include `has_many :item_options` in `Item` and `Option` models

Answer (score 1):

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many item_options
  has_many :options, through: :item_options
end

class ItemOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :option
end

class Option < ActiveRecord::Base    
    has_many :item_options
    has_many :items, through: :item_options
end
```

If the intermediate model `ItemOption` is only going to preserve the ids of two related models, you can also use: [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association.